# How to bind an Event Handler to a dynamically created control inside of a collection?

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, eventhandler

I'm working with C# again, and trying to catch up with some of the newer aspects, as the last time I worked with it LINQ didn't yet exist.  I am trying to create a calendar (not a date picker) in a Windows Store app, and dynamically create most of the controls.  When a date is clicked/tapped, I want it to display information in a RichTextBlock.  That part isn't the problem...I have a Grid control, and can iterate through the month to create the calendar by creating RichTextBlocks in a List called, naturally enough, calBlocks.  This is the part that is giving me fits:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.DaysInMonth(CurrentDate.Year, CurrentDate.Month); i++)
    {
        calBlocks.Add(new RichTextBlock());
        calBlocks[i].Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(calBlock_Clicked);
    }
```

I've defined a calBlock_Clicked handler, but it never seems to be reached. I seem to be missing something, and I think it's something pretty basic, but I just can't seem to see it.

If you're interested, this is the calBlock_Clicked handler.  It's pretty basic, and just for debugging purposes at the moment:

```
    void calBlock_Clicked(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Paragraph MainHeader = new Paragraph();
        Run HeaderDate = new Run();

        HeaderDate.Text = "This would be a long format date";

        MainHeader.Inlines.Add(HeaderDate);

        TestBlock.Blocks.Add(MainHeader);
    }
```

I have looked, but I haven't seen anything that answered exactly this...there have been a few similar posts, but nothing that quite answered my questions.  If there already are, please point me to them!

Comment: Your code looks okay at first glance. Are `DateBlock` or `monthCal` relevant to the problematic code? Also, are you testing whether `calBlock_Clicked` is hit using a breakpoint?

Comment: Good point, sorry.  I was actually going to get rid of the monthCal bit, but apparently I didn't before I posted.  That's simply a basic structure that I'm using to generate `Run`s .  I will edit the original post to remove references to that.  Also, I have tried setting a breakpoint, and it never comes up.

Comment: Try setting `IsTextSelectionEnabled ` property to `false` when you construct them. That should re-enable the event.

Comment: Glad to help :-) I added it as an answer.

Comment: I accepted it as an answer, and I'd upvote it if I had enough reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `IsTextSelectionEnabled` property of your `RichTextBlock` to `false` upon construction.

This will re-enable the `Tapped` event.

Example:

```
calBlocks.Add(new RichTextBlock() { IsTextSelectionEnabled = false });
```